# Opening word template as a template not a document (from Excel)

Tags: excel, templates, ms-word, vba

I'm building some reporting templates.  They are all based on a 'master template' with a particular layout and tables.  I then have an Excel table which I am using to populate the master template then save as a new template for the reporting of that specific item.  I had this working fine, but realize my code was opening a new document based on the master template then saving as the new templates.

That's fine, but my master template now includes a userform on the Document_New() event.  As such, I need it to open as a TEMPLATE so I can populate and save as the new template.  With the code opening the master as a document rather than a template, it's running the userform immediately.  I need it to let me open the master, populate it and save it, then, when a report needs to be made, the new templates are opened THEN the userform is run.

My code (in the excel file) to open the master template is:

```
    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application   'a new instance of Word
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document          'our new Word template
    Dim myWordFile As String            'path to Word template

    myWordFile = "W:\Entity\Inspect\WORD\INSPECTION TEMPLATES\Inspection Template - 20160519.dotm"

    wdDoc.SaveAs "W:\Entity\Inspect\WORD\INSPECTION TEMPLATES\Report Templates\" & vUnit & "\" & vItem & " Thorough Examination.dotm", wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled

    wdApp.Documents.Close
```

Comment: You don't actually seem to have posted the bit of code that opens the word template! But using the standard Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(myWordFile) *should* open the template as a template (and not fire Document_New()) . Is that not what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You could try temporarily disabling macros:

```
tmpAut = wrdApp.Application.AutomationSecurity   'cache current setting
wdApp.Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

'do your thing here

wdApp.Application.AutomationSecurity = tmpAut 'reset previous
```

Comment: Hi Tim.  That worked to prevent the form loading whilst populating etc., but the resultant template doesn't have the userform or word code in it.

When the master template (which userform and code) is opened as a document and saved as the new template, it loses the userform.

Comment: Maybe update your question to add the new code you tried.